# Use ImageMagick 7 to create and modify a batch of tiles into repeating images

Tags: imagemagick, batch-processing, tile

Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-55 Q16 x64

I have a Windows folder full of hundreds of TIFF tiles (can repeat seamlessly) of various fabric scans. I need to generate a 10" x 10" image of each fabric based on each tile's dpi. I would like to then scale each image down to a 1000x1000 JPEG with 85% quality. The end result would be a folder full of 1000x1000 images that look like 10"x10" swatches of the scanned fabrics.

I imagine a successful script would do something like this for each tile in the folder:

1. get a tile
2. get the tile dpi
3. dpi * inches = canvas size
4. create a canvas for the new tiled image
5. repeat the tile to fill the canvas
6. format, scale, optimize the new image
7. save the new image in different folder

I've been able to create tiles one at a time and modify images as a batch. But I can't figure out how to modify and tile or tile in a batch. I also don't know how to retrieve the dpi and use it to modify the canvas size.

This command creates a single 5000x5000 tiled image (but seems to change the dpi).

```
magick mogrify -path tiled -size 5000x5000 tile:tile01.tif
```

This command formats, scales, and optimizes a batch of images:

```
magick mogrify -path resized -format jpg -resize 1000x1000 -quality 85 *.tif
```

Here are two sample tiles. They are 28 dpi and 237 dpi.

[image: tile01.tif]

[image: tile02.tif]

And here's what a 10"x10" swatch of each would look like if you cut it from the roll and took a photo.

[image]

[image]

Here's my final solution. It uses the dpi of each tile to calculate and fill the resolution needed for a 10"x10" swatch. It then scales the image down to a few different resolutions setting the dpi consistent with its 10"x10" swatch size.

```
FOR %I in (I:\Covers\tiles\*.tif) DO magick %I -write mpr:tile -set 
option:dnsty "%x" -size "%[fx:dnsty*10]x%[fx:dnsty*10]" +delete tile:mpr:tile ^
( -clone 0 -resize "1000x1000\>" -format jpg -quality 85 -set option:wdth "%w" -density "%[fx:wdth/10]" -units pixelsperinch -write I:\Covers\tiles\tiled\Large\%~nI.jpg ) ^
( -clone 0 -resize "800x800\>" -format jpg -quality 85 -set option:wdth "%w" -density "%[fx:wdth/10]" -units pixelsperinch -write I:\Covers\tiles\tiled\Medium\%~nI.jpg ) ^
( -clone 0 -resize "400x400\>" -format jpg -quality 85 -set option:wdth "%w" -density "%[fx:wdth/10]" -units pixelsperinch -write I:\Covers\tiles\tiled\Small\%~nI.jpg ) ^
( -clone 0 -resize "220x220\>" -format jpg -quality 85 -set option:wdth "%w" -density "%[fx:wdth/10]" -units pixelsperinch -write I:\Covers\tiles\tiled\Largeviews\%~nI.jpg ) ^
( -clone 0 -resize "120x120\>" -format jpg -quality 85 -set option:wdth "%w" -density "%[fx:wdth/10]" -units pixelsperinch -write I:\Covers\tiles\tiled\Thumbnails\%~nI.jpg ) null:
```

Simplified with Mark's input:

```
FOR %I in (I:\Covers\tiles\*.tif) DO magick %I -write mpr:tile -set option:dnsty "%x" -size "%[fx:dnsty*10]x%[fx:dnsty*10]" +delete tile:mpr:tile ^
( -clone 0 -resize "1000x1000\>" -quality 85 -set option:wdth "%w" -density "%[fx:wdth/10]" -units pixelsperinch -write I:\Covers\tiles\tiled\Large\%~nI.jpg ) ^
( -clone 0 -resize "800x800\>" -set option:wdth "%w" -density "%[fx:wdth/10]" -units pixelsperinch -write I:\Covers\tiles\tiled\Medium\%~nI.jpg ) ^
( -clone 0 -resize "400x400\>" -set option:wdth "%w" -density "%[fx:wdth/10]" -units pixelsperinch -write I:\Covers\tiles\tiled\Small\%~nI.jpg ) ^
( -clone 0 -resize "220x220\>" -set option:wdth "%w" -density "%[fx:wdth/10]" -units pixelsperinch -write I:\Covers\tiles\tiled\Largeviews\%~nI.jpg ) ^
( -clone 0 -resize "120x120\>" -set option:wdth "%w" -density "%[fx:wdth/10]" -units pixelsperinch -write I:\Covers\tiles\tiled\Thumbnails\%~nI.jpg ) null:
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you worked out how to iterate over your files? Do you know how to process a single file? Do you have sample input and output images? Do all your files have a dpi? Do they all have the same dpi?

Comment: Post an example tiff file. I do not understand your question. How can it be tiled to some size, but also resized to 1000x1000? Please clarify your question or show a diagram or example input and output. ImageMagick can tile images to any size you want in pixels. If you want the result in inches, then you can read the input meta data for the density and then compute how many pixels to create. What is your IM version?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I've added the requested details.

Comment: @fmw42, I've added the requested details.

Comment: You can omit all the `-format jpeg` parameters from your commands as it will be automatically inferred from the output filename. You only need specify `-quality 85` one time at the start and you can omit the rest as the setting will be remembered until changed.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, can I also specify `-units pixelsperinch` just one time? Should I put `-quality 85 -units pixelsperinch` at the end of the first line before I start cloning?

Comment: Try it and check with `magick identify -verbose XXX.jpg`. I would put the quality and dpi before the first parentheses as global settings but try it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want, given you last question, using a fairly current version of ImageMagick 7 (only), you can do the following:

Input:

[image]

```
magick I6xQd.png -write mpr:tile -set option:dens "%x" -size "%[fx:dens*10]x%[fx:dens*10]" +delete tile:mpr:tile result.png
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly the piece I was missing! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion, thought I still am not sure exactly what you want, would be to simply write a script loop over all the files in your directory and use ImageMagick magick (not magick mogrify) to do the following:

[image]

```
magick tweed.png -write mpr:img +delete -size 1000x1000 tile:mpr:img -density 100 -units pixelsperinch -quality 85 tweed_tiled.jpg
```

[image]

The resulting tiled image has a resolution of 100 dpi. So for 1000 pixels it will print 10 inches.

```
Image:
  Filename: tweed_tiled.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1000x1000+0+0
  Resolution: 100x100
  Print size: 10x10
  Units: PixelsPerInch
```

**Alternate**

You can use magick mogrify to process a whole folder of image using the following command to produce results like I have shown above:

```
cd desktop/in
magick mogrify -path ../out -format jpg -set option:distort:viewport 1000x1000+0+0 -virtual-pixel tile -filter point -distort SRT 0 -density 100 -units pixelsperinch -quality 85 *.png
```

Comment: This is helpful and close to what I need, but I think I'm not explaining one thing clearly. These are scans of real fabrics with accurate dpi information. I need to use the original dpi info to tile a 10"x10" image so the result looks like I cut a 10"x10" swatch out of the actual fabric and took a picture of it. Then I can scale the image to any size and it will still look like a photo of a real 10"x10" swatch.

Comment: I updated the question to show what the tiled images should look like.

Comment: I still do not understand. You want to tile only as much as it will print 10 in x 10 in using the original density? If so, where does the 1000x1000 size come in.

Comment: These aren't for print. If I generate a 10"x10" swatch from a 300dpi tile, it will be 3000x3000. If I make a 10"x10" swatch from a 200dpi tile, it will be 2000x2000. Then I need to scale them both down to 1000x1000 for web use.

Comment: Sorry, that still is not clear to me. Your first image is 28 dpi and has size 208x181. What steps do you want to do to process it in terms of pixel sizes. So 10 in would be 10*28=280 px. So if it is tiled to 280 pixels, it would print as 10 inches.  From there what do you want to do -- tile to 1000 or resize to 1000?

Comment: I would actually leave a 28dpi tile 280x280. No point upscaling it to 1000x1000 and tiling to 1000x1000 would not maintain an accurate representation. I only have a few that are that low-res, but most of the others were too big to upload in my question.

Comment: I still do not understand your question nor what you need done. Please give a specific example with the input dpi and pixel dimensions and how you want it processed. Then what will be the output dpi and pixel dimension.

Comment: If a tile has a dpi of x, then I need to tile it over a 10x by 10x canvas and then resize it down to 1000 by 1000.
If a tile has a dpi of 250, then I need to tile it over a 2500 by 2500 canvas and then resize it down to 1000 by 1000.
If a tile has a dpi of 125, then I need to tile it over a 1250 by 1250 canvas and then resize it down to 1000 by 1000. 
(Original tile dimensions and final swatch dpi don't matter. If the tile is below 100 dpi, I'll skip the resize step since there's no reason to enlarge the image.)

Comment: It looks like %x will return x resolution (density). Is there a way to do something like -size %x*10x%x*10

Comment: See my second answer